# Mocking ES Modules when running the Vite development server

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, stubbing, vite, es6-modules

I need to find out how I can instruct Vite to replace references to local/relative modules at runtime. The use case here is the test runner [mocha-vite-puppeteer](https://github.com/larsthorup/mocha-vite-puppeteer), which uses Vite to run tests, but then stubbing of modules of course does not work when using Node machinery such as proxyquire or rewire.

So I basically need to either be tipped of some existing software that can help me in doing this, or some tips on how to create my own "vite-proxyquire" using `import.meta` and friends.

A normal use for temporarily stubbing out `./my-ugly-module` might be that you want to avoid loading some sub-dependency that has some ugly transitive dependencies that suck the entire application tree into your little test, or you want to avoid loading a sub-dependency that has some ugly side effects on the global state.

## Existing solutions

[Modern Web](https://modern-web.dev), a refreshing "bundler- and frameworkless" approach to web development using standard tools, talk a bit about the issue around how the immutable nature of ES Modules prevent usual stubbing patterns. They present a solution in the form of *Import Maps*, which essentially would be similar to the alias config in Vite (Rollup really), mapping a path to a module to some other file. The problem with a static solution like this is that it would replace *all* imports of a given module, not just for a single test. [Modern Web has a solution to this](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/writing-tests/mocking/) where they have chosen to use a custom html page for each such test. To make this less of a hassle with regards to running, they then have a custom test runner that handles dealing with all these extra test html files. Doing something like that could be one way of fixing it, but it would require developing quite a bit of middleware/plugin code IMHO to make it work transparently with Vite. Without any advanced tooling it would also introduce a lot of extra files that seems a bit of a downside compared to todays imperative mocking of dependencies with proxyquire, Jest or Test Double from inside of the test files.